# Xcode adding new library

Tags: c++, xcode

I ran into a problem I just can't fix. The problem is Im trying to add a new library to xcode and never did it before. I don't really now if the problem is library related or me adding a new library to xcode.
The Library Im trying to add is tidylib (tidy-html5).

```
#include <tidy.h>
#include <tidybuffio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv )
{
    const char* input = "<title>Foo</title><p>Foo!";
    TidyBuffer output = {0};
    TidyBuffer errbuf = {0};
    int rc = -1;
    Bool ok;

    TidyDoc tdoc = tidyCreate();                     // Initialize "document"
    printf( "Tidying:\t%s\n", input );

    ok = tidyOptSetBool( tdoc, TidyXhtmlOut, yes );  // Convert to XHTML
    if ( ok )
        rc = tidySetErrorBuffer( tdoc, &errbuf );      // Capture diagnostics
    if ( rc >= 0 )
        rc = tidyParseString( tdoc, input );           // Parse the input
    if ( rc >= 0 )
        rc = tidyCleanAndRepair( tdoc );               // Tidy it up!
    if ( rc >= 0 )
        rc = tidyRunDiagnostics( tdoc );               // Kvetch
    if ( rc > 1 )                                    // If error, force output.
        rc = ( tidyOptSetBool(tdoc, TidyForceOutput, yes) ? rc : -1 );
    if ( rc >= 0 )
        rc = tidySaveBuffer( tdoc, &output );          // Pretty Print

    if ( rc >= 0 )
    {
        if ( rc > 0 )
            printf( "\nDiagnostics:\n\n%s", errbuf.bp );
        printf( "\nAnd here is the result:\n\n%s", output.bp );
    }
    else
        printf( "A severe error (%d) occurred.\n", rc );

    tidyBufFree( &output );
    tidyBufFree( &errbuf );
    tidyRelease( tdoc );
    return rc;
}
```

My problem is that I get the following error all the time and I just can't fix it:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "_tidyBufFree", referenced from:
> _main in main.o
> "_tidyCleanAndRepair", referenced from:
> _main in main.o
> "_tidyCreate", referenced from:
> _main in main.o
> "_tidyOptSetBool", referenced from:
> _main in main.o
> "_tidyParseString", referenced from:
> _main in main.o
> "_tidyRelease", referenced from:
> _main in main.o
> "_tidyRunDiagnostics", referenced from:
> _main in main.o
> "_tidySaveBuffer", referenced from:
> _main in main.o
> "_tidySetErrorBuffer", referenced from:
> _main in main.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```
>
> What I did?
>
> ```
> I set up the header search path to "/usr/local/Cellar/tidy-html5/5.6.0/include/"
> I set up the library search path to "/usr/local/Cellar/tidy-html5/5.6.0/lib/"
> I also tried to set other link flags to "-ltidylib"
> ```

System?

- MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4
- XCode 9.4.1

**Solution**
You have to use "-ltidy" instead of "-ltidylib" under other Other Linker Flags

Comment: Did you try going into the build settings and adding tidylib to the"Linked frameworks and libraries"? (Located in the bottom of the "General" section of the project settings.)Try going there and clicking the little plus button, then click "Add other", find tidylib, and add it. Those undefined symbol errors mean that though you might have set up your search paths right, the library still isn't being included. Doing what I just said to do will hopefully fix this. (It's always worked for me at least in the past.)

Comment: The solution was to us in other linker flags: "-ltidy"

Comment: You can also save yourself a lot of trouble by just using '#include <tidy/tidy.h>' as Tidy is preinstalled on Macintosh computers, along with a host of other stuff life Ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

Select your target (typically the app you're building) and click on the Build Phases tab. Build phases are the different steps needed for building, such as checking dependencies, compiling, copying resources, etc. One of them is "Link Binary with Libraries", and it includes a list of libraries and frameworks that your project should link. Click on the `+` button to add a new item to the list, and choose the library you want to add. Then build.

Comment: The method I describe above should work fine, but so will using a linker flag to link to a library. In that case, you'd want to read the documentation for the linker. The man page for `ld` and the [docs for llvm-ld](http://releases.llvm.org/2.5/docs/CommandGuide/html/llvm-ld.html) both say that you should leave off the "lib".